# My washer quit and I am trying to remove the hoses. How do I know if the water is turned off. It sprays water no matter which way I I turn the knobs

Tags: water, washing-machine

I need help. I can't figure out how to make sure the water is off.

Comment: It would really really help to post one or more photos of the hose connections (at both ends if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Taps or stopcocks get closed by turning them clockwise.

The quarter turn isolation valves are open when the handle is inline with the valve and closed when the handle is at 90 degrees to the valve or "across” the valve.

Once the valve is shut, there is always a little water that comes out due to the flexible pipes contracting.

If the valves are “shut” and lots of water is coming out then the valve may be stuck.

Comment: Some quarter-turn valves you can put the handle on any of 4 ways. Once on, it's limited to just a quarter turn, but there's no way of knowing just by looking which is on or off [logic tells you, of course, that it's 90° from where you found it;)

Comment: @Tetsujin most of the isolation valves I have come across have two flats on the shaft so only 2 positions are ever possible and the handles can be plastic or cast monkey metal..

Comment: Being stuck is not uncommon in my experience; I've owned 3 homes and only 1 of them had working washer valves when I moved in. The others required replacing, which we found shortly after turning the water back on (houses had been winterized/utility shut off before we moved in).

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking at them , or over them , turn the knobs in a clock-wise position.  This is off.  Then start a cycle on the washer to drain the pressure in the hoses.  You can then remove the hoses with just some water dripping.